# Node passport js + redirect not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, google-authentication, passport-google-oauth

I am using node js with express.
I am trying to implement passport google auth.

When i click the google login link its asking gmail username and password, then the **Allow**, **Deny** buttons,

Once i click the Allow button its loading keep on.

```
var passport             = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var configAuth = require('./config');


passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID : configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret : configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL : configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL,
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
       /*
       User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
                return done(err, user);
              });*/
       console.log("rrrrrr");
       return done(err, accessToken);

  }
));

router.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'] }));

router.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
           console.log("rddddddddddrrrrr");

    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Comment: Do you see `rddddddddddrrrrr` getting logged?

Comment: no, I didn't get.